# Real representations of SO(n) and U(n)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

I would like to get some references where I can find the theory of the real representations of $\mathbf{SO}(n)$ and $\mathbf{U}(n)$.

In particular, I would like to know for which dimensions there exist irreducible representations of these groups and for which dimension, how many non-equivalent representations are?.

Comment: See Math Overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227869/is-there-a-formula-for-the-frobenius-schur-indicator-of-a-rep-of-a-lie-group

Answer (score 5):

Take  a  look  at  John Frank Adams' Lectures on Lie groups. W. A. Benjamin, Inc., New York-Amsterdam 1969 xii+182 pp..  chapter 6.

Answer (score 3):

Read about [Frobenius-Schur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator) anywhere. In a nutshell a complex irreducible $V$ of complex dimension $n$ can give 1 or 2 real irreducibles, whose real dimensions are $n$ or $2n$. This can be easily determined by computing the FS-indicator or dimensions of invariants in both $S^2V$ and $\Lambda^2 V$. The latter can be done in [Lie](http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/form.html) for each particular representation.

Comment: Minor correction: $n$ or $2n$, not $n$ or $n/2$.

Answer (score 3):

The book by Broecker and tom Dieck (Representations of Compact groups, Springer Graduate Texts in Math) has a very useful section about real, complex and quaternionic representations and how to pass between them.